# mbrtowc: howto determine number of characters to skip if null character is read

Tags: c, character-encoding, c99

According to the C99 specification the `mbrtowc` function returns `0`

> if the next n or fewer bytes complete the multibyte character that
>   corresponds to the null wide character (which is the value stored).

What is the best way to continue reading the input immediately after the encoded null character?

My current solution is to convert the null wide character with the given encoding in order to determine the number of input bytes to skip for the next call to `mbrtowc`. But there might be a more elegant way to do this.

Additionally I wonder what the rationale behind this behaviour of `mbrtowc` might be.

Comment: Just to know why do you want use wide character? If it's to handle Unicode you are wrong.

Comment: I want to count characters.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you use `strlen()` of `wcslen()`? XY problem? Feel free to add your code.

Comment: Because I do not have strings but files with certain encodings. The files are parsed character by character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One byte. The null byte always represents the null character regardless of shift state, and cannot participate as part of a multibyte character. The source for this is:

> 5.2.1.2 Multibyte characters
>
> ...
>
> - A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character independent of shift state. Such a byte shall not occur as part of any other multibyte character.

Comment: Does this really help? When reading external stored data with a fixed length encoding, e.g. UTF-32, I would expect the null character to be encoded in more than on byte. To skip these bytes in the input buffer one needs to know their number.

Comment: @aventurin: UTF-32 is not a multibyte encoding. You cannot read it with `mbrtowc`.

Comment: I didn't know that, but expected that there would be a mechanism in standard c to read files with arbitrary encoding. And even if UTF-32 would not qualify as a multibyte encoding, there might be others, such as Modified UTF-8, that do not encode the null character as a single byte. But now I guess that these also would not qualify as multibyte encodings in standard c's sense.

Comment: @aventurin: `mbrtowc` is not even a mechanism to read files with arbitrary multibyte encodings; it's only for reading files in the encoding of the locale. Plain C has no functionality for reading arbitrary/well-known encodings by name; you get this with POSIX in the `iconv` interface, or you can just implement it yourself (or use somebody else's library) since the encodings are fully-specified and don't need to be abstracted for portability.